# Babel Webpack Error: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I am trying to lazy load some React components like so:

node: `v10.15.2`

```js
const Library = React.lazy(() => import('./components/Library'))`
```

My error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (51:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| var Library = React.lazy(function () {
>   return import('./components/Library');
| });
```

Webpack Config:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: {
    options: {
      presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/react', '@babel/preset-flow'],
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
        '@babel/syntax-dynamic-import',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        '@babel/plugin-syntax-throw-expressions',
      ],
    },
    loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory',
  },
},
```

`package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "css-modulesify": "^0.28.0",
    "hls.js": "^0.8.9",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.2.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "qs": "^6.5.1",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-collapsible": "^2.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-loadable": "^5.3.1",
    "react-scrollspy": "^3.3.5",
    "react-select": "^1.2.1",
    "react-share": "^2.2.0",
    "react-sticky": "^6.0.1",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^2.0.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.3.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "smooth-scroll": "^12.1.5",
    "video-react": "^0.9.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "browser-sync": "^2.23.6",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.10",
    "eslint": "^4.17.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.44.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.6.1",
    "flow-bin": "^0.68.0",
    "lodash.assign": "^4.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.2",
    "webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.11.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
```

Is there anything blatantly obvious I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: check node version

Comment: @Revansiddh v8.11.1

Comment: Have you tried to change your 'syntax-dynamic-import' into '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'?

Comment: I had similar issue just updated node to 10.15 using nvm, and fixed that issue

Comment: @Revansiddh using nvm, updated to 10.5.2, and updated `syntax-dynamic-import` to `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import', still not working 

Answer (score 3):

I found it!

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8656#issuecomment-456061673

> remove node_modules
>
> remove package-lock.json
>
> npm install
>
> npm update acorn --depth 20
>
> npm dedupe

and make sure `acorn@^6.0.0`

it helped me